# Angular: Ensure Services is Complete before Running Next Step

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

We are currently using Angular.
Component is receiving data from API. After getting API Data, it goes through Data Services which transform and customize the data, concatenate First Last Name, rounds dollar amounts, makes calculations, etc.
The last step tries to populate the Sales year in a Dropdown, after parsing all the data.

```
this.webStoreSearchHttpService.GetAllCustomerSalesData(this.customerId).subscribe((response) => {

  this.customerList= customerDataService.createCustomerList(response);
  this.productList = customerDataService.createProductAnalysis(response);
  this.salesList= customerDataService.createSalesList(response);
  this.salesYearList= customerDataService.createYearList(response);

  this.salesYearItemCurrent = _.cloneDeep(this.salesYearList[0]);   <--- this goes into a Mat Select Dropdown
```

However, correlating data does not appear after selecting web dropdown, because the Data Services is not finished parsing/created yet, even though its in original API subscribe.

What I am trying to do, is make sure all 4 Data services are totally complete, and Then populate salesYear. How can this be done with Angular typescript ?

The data services can be run in Parallel, however last step is salesYear population in dropdown.

The methods return class arrays, not promises or observables.

Comment: Could you show your HTML ? Also do the Values appear later ? With a latency or not appear at all in the Mat Dropdown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You added the sentece `The methods return class arrays, not promises or observables.`. This implies that you have no possibility from outside to wait for asynchroneous calls to finish. Hence you have to change the return value of the `customerDataService` methods. I am assuming that inside this methods some asynchroneous stuff is done, because you say `What I am trying to do, is make sure all 4 Data services are totally complete`.

**Old version**

To answer your question one have to know what the `customerDataService` methods return type is. Do the method return `Promise` or `Observable`? Depending on that you can use `Promise.all` or `forkJoin` operator to wait for all methods to finish and then execute the select population. This is an example using observables:

```
this.webStoreSearchHttpService.GetAllCustomerSalesData(this.customerId).subscribe(response => {
    forkJoin([
        customerDataService.createCustomerList(response),
        customerDataService.createProductAnalysis(response),
        customerDataService.createSalesList(response),
        customerDataService.createYearList(response)
    ]).subscribe(([customerList, productList, salesList, salesYearList]) => {
        this.customerList = customerList;
        this.productList = productList;
        this.salesList = salesList;
        this.salesYearList = salesYearList;
        this.salesYearItemCurrent = _.cloneDeep(this.salesYearList[0]);
    });
});
```

or even better to avoid the inner subscription and has only one subscription:

```
this.webStoreSearchHttpService.GetAllCustomerSalesData(this.customerId).pipe(
    flatMap(response => 
        forkJoin([
            customerDataService.createCustomerList(response),
            customerDataService.createProductAnalysis(response),
            customerDataService.createSalesList(response),
            customerDataService.createYearList(response)
        ])
    )
).subscribe(([customerList, productList, salesList, salesYearList]) => {
    this.customerList = customerList;
    this.productList = productList;
    this.salesList = salesList;
    this.salesYearList = salesYearList;
    this.salesYearItemCurrent = _.cloneDeep(this.salesYearList[0]);
});
```

Comment: These methods return class arrays, not promises or observables.

Comment: But then how do you want to wait for the method to be finished? I assume something asynchroneous does happen inside the `customerDataService` methods, because you said `Data Service is not finished parsing/created yet`.

Comment: hi I am not allowed to change the data types returned from the four service methods, can you provide a quick code sample for your new update? thanks

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 If you cannot change the return value, then you cannot solve the problem. If something async happenes, you have to return a promise/observable to wait for it to finish.